# using fgets and strcmp in C

Tags: c, fgets, strcmp

I'm trying to get a string input from the user and then run different functions depending on the input they've entered.

For example, say I asked, "What is your favorite fruit?" and I want the program to comment depending on what they enter...I'm not sure how to do this. Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char fruit[100];

main() {
    printf("What is your favorite fruit?\n");
    fgets (fruit, 100, stdin);
    if (strcmp(fruit, "apple")) {
        printf("Watch out for worms!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("You should have an apple instead.\n");
        }

}
```

When I run the program, no matter what I enter, it never does the else statement.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `strcmp` returns `0` (which will evaluate as false) to indicate that the two strings are equal.

Comment: Does it **really** hurt to read the documentation of the functions you are trying to use?

Comment: Also , don't use `main()` use `int main(void)` instead .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note two things in your code:

1. fgets keeps the trailing '\n'. the associated char in fruit should be replaced with a '\0' before comparing with the string "apple".
2. strcmp return 0 when two strings are the same, so the if clause should be changed based on what you mean.(The fruit and "apple" be equivalent in the if clause)
3. Standard usage of C main function is `int main(){ return 0;}`

The revised code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char fruit[100];

int main() {
    printf("What is your favorite fruit?\n");
    fgets (fruit, 100, stdin);
    fruit[strlen(fruit)-1] = '\0';
    if (strcmp(fruit, "apple") == 0) {
        printf("Watch out for worms!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("You should have an apple instead.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The above is the correct one, Because '\n' is taken by fgets as the end of string so replace it with '\0' is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `if` condition to the following:

```
if(strcmp(fruit,"apple") == 0)
```

`strcmp` returns 0 strings if match. You should always compare the result using `==` operator

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp` returns 0 if the inputs match, some value>0 if the left is "greater" than the right, some value<0 if the left is "lesser" than the right. So usually you want to simply test for equality with `strcmp(...)==0`. But there is also the *clever* version: `!strcmp(...)`. Even if you don't use this style, it's useful to learn to recognize it.

And remember that `fgets` does not remove the newline character `'\n'` from the string.

Comment: It removes if the length of string is `arraysize-1`.

Comment: Even then I wouldn't say that the newline is *removed*, but maybe *withheld* or *pending*.

Comment: I should have used quotes around **removes** , It ain't the right word obviously ..... actually it retains `'\n'` if string is small enough for it to be accomodated otherwise it doesn't .

Comment: Note that your description of the return values of `strcmp()` is wrong; the values will be 0 on equality (you said that too), but when the first argument is 'smaller' than the second, the return value will just be negative, not necessarily -1; similarly, for 'greater', the return value will be positive, not necessarily +1.  See [`strcmp()` behaviour in 32-bit and 64-bit systems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095575/strcmp-behaviour-in-32-bit-and-64-bit-systems/18095632#18095632)